# SQL query - show if not have both

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like:

Table name: "interactions"

```
id: number 
type: text
user_id: number
```

I wanna get all of the user_ids that have a row with type="type_A" but not have a row with type="type_B"

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `not exists`

```
select distinct user_id from interactions i
where type='type_A' and 
not exists (select 1 from interactions i1 where i.user_id=i1.user_id and type='type_B')
```

Another option could be

```
select user_id from interactions
group by user_id 
having min(type)='type_A' and max(type)='type_A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AND condition in SQL

It goes like this:

WHERE condition1
AND condition2
...
AND condition_n;

See documentation https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php

In addition, you can make it like not equal to something.